# RDS dashboard number of instances includes documentDB nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When I go to the RDS Dashboard in the AWS console, I see:

DB Instances (12/40)

The documentation says that the above 12/40 means: 12 RDS instances out of our allowance of 40. And we could request to increase our 40 allocation, for sure.

But I'm confused by that number 12; when I list my RDS instances, there are only 9 database instances. I have no idea why it says 12. Then I run this AWS RDS command:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier,ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers]'
```

... and it does list my 9 RDS instances plus 3 documentDB nodes, for a total of 12!

So, is it true that the DocumentDB nodes count towards our RDS limit of 40? Or is this an RDS bug? I'm asking because we're trying to reduce our costs and everyone got confused by that number of instances (it really should not list the 3 mongo/docdb nodes)...